# Class in Java accessors

Tags: java

Consider this code:

```
package question.pkg2;

public class Car {

    private int wheels;
    private String color;
    private boolean roadworthy;
    public int year = 1982;

    public Car() {

    }

    public Car(int numberOfWheels, String color, boolean roadworthy, int yearOfManufactured) {
        wheels = numberOfWheels;
        this.color = color;
        this.roadworthy = roadworthy;
        year = yearOfManufactured;

    }

    public int getNumberOfWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;

    }

    public String changeColor() {
        return color;

    }

    public boolean getRoadworthiness() {
        return roadworthy;
    }

    public String getYear(int checkYear) {
        if (year < 1982) {
            year = checkYear;
            System.out.println("it is not considered roadworthy");
        }

    }
}
```

My question is am going to check the year but I got error statement,whats the meaning of this statement "missing return statement"?

Comment: Please consider reading [ask] - it's unclear what you're asking and this is tagged 'less' which I'm not sure why?

Comment: It means that your method does not have a `return` statement.

Comment: Seems like you had wrongly tagged it under Less (CSS preprocessor), so I re-tagged it to Java as the code seems to be Java code.

Comment: In particular `getYear` should `return year`

Comment: Please read a tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature is

```
public String getYear(int checkYear)
```

So you need to return a `null`, a `String`.

And here's something you need to consider:

- Your method is "getYear" so is `String` a proper return type?
- You're modifying a field in a "getSomething" method, it might cause confusions.
- You have a `roadworthy` field, and in `getYear` it prints message related to "roadworthy"; if the `year` is changed in `getYear`, should `roadworthy` also be updated?

Comment: Since String is **final**, nothing can **extend** String

Comment: Yeah forget that. Edited.

Comment: based on what I understand it can't return string but it should return int for year

Answer (score 0):

Your method:

```
public String getYear(int checkYear) {
    if (year < 1982) {
        year = checkYear;
        System.out.println("it is not considered roadworthy");
    }

}
```

If you want the method to return the year as a String, you will need to convert the int to a String
So it need to be like this:

```
public String getYear(int checkYear) {
    if (year < 1982) {
        year = checkYear;
        System.out.println("it is not considered roadworthy");
    }
    return Integer.toString(year);
}
```

Or if you just want it to write to the consol if **year < 1982** 
So It is have to be like this:

```
public void getYear(int checkYear) {
    if (year < 1982) {
        year = checkYear;
        System.out.println("it is not considered roadworthy");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing return in your getYear method. When you decalred some method with a return type other than void, you must always return a cpmpatible value from that method. Otherwise you will get that error.

```
public String getYear(int checkYear) {
       if (year < 1982) {
            year = checkYear;
            System.out.println("it is not considered roadworthy");
       }
       return "some string value that you want to return"; 
}
```